# Is there a way to create a new IME layout?

Tags: windows, layout, keyboard, ime

I have a hard time finding information on how I would go about developing a keyboard layout that uses IME without it just being information on how I can simply add a new keyboard layout that uses the microsoft IME or how I can use the Microsoft IME in my applications.

What I want to do is making the whole thing from scratch. It's not supposed to be for an existing language (so it's not like any of the existing IMEs would be an alternative) but, obviously, having information on how I'd go about developing an IME for Japanese, Chinese or Korean is also a nice thing.

Google has their own IME that is cross platform so I assume that it is possible to do it but I just can't find any information on it.

Thanks

The OS is Windows 8.1, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but I don't like open questions (to which I know the answer) ;-)

Hope it still helps: Microsoft's Keyboard Layout Creator (MS KLC) is what you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Comment: unfortunately, this is not helping as MSKLC does not allow you to create a custom keyboard layout based off of Microsoft IME.

Comment: Eh, right - I wonder why I then posted this - I have no excuse than to say that that boy was a much younger version of me ;)  Sry for the confusion!